# JMeter with gRPC Java Client and BeanShell Sampler

Tags: jmeter, grpc

why it's not possible to run this native Java gRPC Client out of the BeanShell Sampler of JMeter:

```
package at.fhj.swd.grpc.client;

import at.fhj.swd.grpc.CalcRequest;
import at.fhj.swd.grpc.CalcResponse;
import at.fhj.swd.grpc.CalcServiceGrpc;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder;

public class GrpcClient {

public static void calc() {
    ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 9090)
            .usePlaintext()
            .build();

    CalcServiceGrpc.CalcServiceBlockingStub stub
            = CalcServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    CalcResponse calcResponse = stub.calc(CalcRequest.newBuilder()
            .setNumber(7)
            .build());

    channel.shutdown();

    System.out.println(calcResponse.getResultList());
    }
}
```

The BeanShell Sampler Script can't create an instance of GrpcCient. (method invocation quoted)

```
import at.fhj.swd.grpc.client.GrpcClient;

GrpcClient grpcClient = new GrpcClient();

//grpcClient.calc();
```

The error:

```
Response code:500
Response message:org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   io/grpc/Channel
```

seems that there was something wrong with an import, but why? The Client runs if its executed without JMeter.

Comment: ManagedChannel extends Channel, but why it's a problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Beanshell](https://beanshell.github.io/) is not 100% compatible with Java so if there are overloaded functions/constructors you need to explicitly specify which one you want via [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it would be sufficient just to choose `groovy` from the Language dropdown and your code will start working as expected. Moreover Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details